# How do I read system information in C++?

Tags: c++, linux, operating-system, system

I'm trying to get information like OS version, hard disk space, disk space available, and installed RAM on a Linux system in C++.  I know I can use `system()` to run different Linux commands and capture their output (which is what I'm currently doing) but I was wondering if there's a better way?  Is there something in the C++ standard library that I can use to get information from the operating system?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using *nix commands via system.

Then do man  scroll to the bottom of the man page and it will usually show you what relevant C system calls are related.

```
Example:  man uname:
SEE ALSO
       uname(2), getdomainname(2), gethostname(2)


Explanation of numbers:

(1): User UNIX Command
(2): Unix and C system calls
(3): C Library routines
(4): Special file names
(5): File formats
(6): 
(7):
(8): System admin commands
```

So if you are using system("uname"). From the man page you can see that there is also a uname C system call (uname(2)). So you can now do a 'man 2 uname' to get information about how to use the C system call uname.

Comment: You can also strace an existing system program (application), if you can handle the noise.  E.g. "strace uname -a"  This shows you ALL the system calls made by that program.  Find the right system call, and you can invoke the same routine from your own program.

Comment: You don't know how happy I am that I don't have to parse the output of system("df").  Thanks alot.  :)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in the C++ Standard library for these purposes. The library you could use is `libhal`, which abstracts the view of programs to the hardware, collecting various informations from `/proc`, `/sys` and others. [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal), scroll down, there seems to be an unofficial C++ binding available too (haven't tested it though, while libhal works also fine for C++ programs). Use the command `lshal` to display all device informations available to HAL.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use [HAL](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/hal) as litb suggests, you can read things straight out of the [/proc filesystem](http://www.redhat.com/docs/manuals/linux/RHL-7.2-Manual/ref-guide/ch-proc.html), provided it's there on your system.  This isn't the most platform-independent way of doing things, and in many cases you'll need to do a little parsing to pick apart the files.

I think HAL abstracts a lot of these details for you, but just know that you can read it straight from /proc if using a library isn't an option.

Answer (score 2):

System information is by definition not portable, so there is no standard solution. Your best bet is using a library that does most of the work for you. One such cross platform library (unlike hal, which is currently Linux specific) is [SIGAR API](http://www.hyperic.com/products/sigar.html), which is open source BTW. I've used it in a C++ project without much trouble (the installation is a bit non-standard but can be figured out easily)